# Add a space or line break to the next line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Need to add a white space or line break before the next line,if the next line starts with blank it has to ignore.

My input  file is like below

```
#qwert      TRWQQA      01       40            /*  this is the sample test  */
                                                  /*     STILL COMING UP... AFTER UP ENQ GOES AWAY                 */
                                                  /*  FEB AND 30TH  */
#TFCDF      DWERTY      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH)
                                                  /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                  /*  (START SCD RTGFG))
                                                  XDYGH #qwert   */
#HYUOIK     YUPOIH      01       40            FEB AND 30TH
                                                   /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                   /*  (START SCD qwert))
                                                   SDFGH #qwert  */
#NHUYUOI    GHTYHD      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR
                                                   (START SCD SDFRE))
#KJYY       ERTYUB      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 03 #qwert OR
                                                    (START SCD DERF))
RTYUH       POMHY       01       40            ERTYUJ RTYUJ
QWERG       PIJHGV      01       40            MNBV LKJH
```

Expected output.

```
#qwert      TRWQQA      01       40            /*  this is the sample test  */
                                                  /*     STILL COMING UP... AFTER UP ENQ GOES AWAY                 */
                                                  /*  FEB AND 30TH  */
                                                
#TFCDF      DWERTY      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH)
                                                  /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                  /*  (START SCD RTGFG))
                                                  XDYGH  #qwert   */
                                                
#HYUOIK     YUPOIH      01       40            FEB AND 30TH
                                                   /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                   /*  (START SCD qwert))
                                                   SDFGH #qwert  */
                                                 
#NHUYUOI    GHTYHD      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR
                                                   (START SCD SDFRE))
                                                 
#KJYY       ERTYUB      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 03 #qwert OR
                                                    (START SCD DERF))
                                                  
RTYUH       POMHY       01       40            ERTYUJ RTYUJ

QWERG       PIJHGV      01       40            MNBV LKJH  **strong text**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `awk` to add a line before each line that does not start with a blank (but avoid doing that for the first line):

```bash
awk 'NR != 1 && /^[^[:blank:]]/ { print "" }; 1' file
```

The command uses two tests.  If both tests are *true*, a blank line is inserted.

- The `NR != 1` test is *true* if the current line is not the first line. This ensures that we don't add a blank line at the start of the output if the first line starts with a non-blank.
- The `/^[^[:blank:]]/` test is *true* if the current line starts with a non-blank character.  Here, a "blank character" means space or tab, a set that may include additional blank characters depending on your locale.

The trailing `1` causes the current line to be outputted unconditionally (it's short-hand for `{ print }`).

Answer (score 6):

Using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '{print (/^[[:blank:]]/ ? "" : sep) $0; sep=ORS}' file
#qwert      TRWQQA      01       40            /*  this is the sample test  */
                                                  /*     STILL COMING UP... AFTER UP ENQ GOES AWAY                 */
                                                  /*  FEB AND 30TH  */

#TFCDF      DWERTY      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH)
                                                  /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                  /*  (START SCD RTGFG))
                                                  XDYGH #qwert   */

#HYUOIK     YUPOIH      01       40            FEB AND 30TH
                                                   /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                   /*  (START SCD qwert))
                                                   SDFGH #qwert  */

#NHUYUOI    GHTYHD      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR
                                                   (START SCD SDFRE))

#KJYY       ERTYUB      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 03 #qwert OR
                                                    (START SCD DERF))

RTYUH       POMHY       01       40            ERTYUJ RTYUJ

QWERG       PIJHGV      01       40            MNBV LKJH
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this, using GNU `awk` :

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 && /^\S/{print ""}1' file
```

- `NR > 1` start after first line to avoid newline on first line
- `&&` AND
- `/^\S/` starting with non white space
- `print ""` print a newline if all conditions are met
- `1` shorthand for `print` on true condition

### Output

```
#qwert      TRWQQA      01       40            /*  this is the sample test  */
                                                  /*     STILL COMING UP... AFTER UP ENQ GOES AWAY                 */
                                                  /*  FEB AND 30TH  */

#TFCDF      DWERTY      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH)
                                                  /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                  /*  (START SCD RTGFG))
                                                  XDYGH #qwert   */

#HYUOIK     YUPOIH      01       40            FEB AND 30TH
                                                   /* AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR       */
                                                   /*  (START SCD qwert))
                                                   SDFGH #qwert  */

#NHUYUOI    GHTYHD      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 01 #qwert OR
                                                   (START SCD SDFRE))

#KJYY       ERTYUB      01       40           (FEB AND 30TH) AND (qwert-01 03 #qwert OR
                                                    (START SCD DERF))

RTYUH       POMHY       01       40            ERTYUJ RTYUJ

QWERG       PIJHGV      01       40            MNBV LKJH
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `perl` you can prefix a newline to a sequence of *newline then not space*:

```
perl -e 'local $/; $_ = <>; s/(\n[^[:space:]])/\n$1/g; print' file
```

Comment: Something similar to `sed -z 's/\n[^[:blank:]]/\n&/g'` with GNU `sed`. Downside is it all needs to be read into memory, but that's ok if the data is small.

Comment: `perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\S/\n$&/g' file` would be a simpler (and perlier) way to write  that.

Comment: Or `perl -g` since 5.36